# Row-level security based on IS_MEMBER function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, security, azure-synapse

### Objective

I'm implementing row-level security (RLS) at Azure Synapse based on Active Directory (AD) authentication. The idea is that customers added to `security_group_A_access` have access to all MY_TABLE rows with column `CATEGORY = 'A'`. See code below.

### Issues

1. `IS_MEMBER` function is invoked once per every row, making `SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY FROM MY_TABLE` query run more than 3 minutes instead of 1 second. [Looks to be a common issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/21414e2e-b524-4677-ad79-a665b523ef67/performance-issues-while-using-the-ismember-function-preemptiveoslookupaccountsid-?forum=sqldatabaseengine).
2. Even by hardcoding `fn_predicate`'s condition with `WHERE CATEGORY = 'A'` (remove `IS_MEMBER` invocation) querying becomes slower. The RLS tables have up to billion of rows and are used for Power BI reports, so performance/response time is very critical for them.

### Questions

1. *Is there any way to call `IS_MEMBER` function no more times than there are security groups?* Means somehow cache the result or store it to global variable, etc.
2. *Is RLS a common approach for billion-rows table with critical performance? Or it's a common practice to create a view per each AD security group?*

### Code

```
CREATE SCHEMA [security]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [security].[fn_predicate](@category_column as varchar(50))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN SELECT 1 AS fn_predicate
  WHERE IS_MEMBER(CONCAT('security_group_', @category_column, '_access')) = 1
GO

GRANT SELECT ON [security].[fn_predicate] TO security_group_A_access
GRANT SELECT ON [security].[fn_predicate] TO security_group_B_access
GO

CREATE SECURITY POLICY MY_TABLE_FILTER
ADD FILTER PREDICATE [security].[fn_predicate]([CATEGORY])
ON [dbo].[MY_TABLE]
WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

### P.S.

I may rephrase this question to - *are there any better options than the 1st one?*

Three possible approaches:

1. Create view per `CATEGORY`, and restrict each group to separate view.

   - *Pros:* The performance of `MY_TABLE` for PBI reporting isn't impacted
   - *Cons:* Number of views. Suppose you have categories A, B, C, D, E. Than you need 5 views. What if there is a user that consists in groups A and C?
2. Apply RLS on top of `MY_TABLE`.

   - *Pros:* My current approach. Simple to implement, no additional tables and views. Scalable, in case of more CATEGORIES, groups or rules will be added.
   - *Cons:* See "Issues" section. Performance of `MY_TABLE` is hardly impacted and isn't acceptable
3. Hybrid approach. Create single `MY_TABLE_VIEW` and apply RLS on top of the view.

   - *Pros:* all benefits of the 2nd option, plus `MY_TABLE` performance  for PBI reporting isn't impacted.
   - *Cons:* still need to solve `IS_MEMBER` performance issue, see 1st point from "Issues" section.

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this problem?

Comment: @Lurifaxel see my solution below.  This may help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a fairly old post but I just wanted to share my solution.  I followed Pattern #2 from Microsoft's suggested patterns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlsecurity/row-level-security-performance-and-common-patterns#pattern-2-row-assignments-in-a-lookup-table

This works using a lookup table.  To do this I created a OwnerAssignments table that contains the name of each AD group that is used in the application.  Then I also have an `Owner` column on my table that I'm applying RLS to.

My predicate function looks like this

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION Security.tvf_securitypredicateOwner(@Owner AS VARCHAR(256))
    RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    RETURN SELECT 1 AS tvf_securitypredicate_result FROM [Security].OwnerAssignments
        WHERE IS_MEMBER(Name) = 1
        AND Name = @Owner
```

Lastly I apply the policy like this

```sql
CREATE SECURITY POLICY MyTableFilter
ADD FILTER PREDICATE Security.tvf_securitypredicateOwner([Owner])
ON dbo.MyTable
WITH (STATE = ON);
GO
```

This greatly improved performance.  It brought a query that took close to a minute to run down to a fraction of a second.